# Finding the first forward difference of $f(x) = x-\frac{q(1-q^x)}{p}+q^{x}c$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

So I am trying to unravel the derivation of some literature equations and one equation I'm struggling at, is to find the first forward difference of the following equation:

$$f(x) = x-\frac{q(1-q^x)}{p}+q^{x}c$$

So, actually, how to find a simplification of

$$f(x+1)-f(x) = ((x+1)-\frac{q(1-q^{x+1})}{p}+q^{x+1}c)-(x-\frac{q(1-q^x)}{p}+q^{x}c))$$

Now I think that the difference between first and third term of the left and right part is equal to

$$1-cq^x$$

But I don't seem to get that second part involved, especially if I look at the desired result, which is:

$$f(x+1)-f(x) = 1-q^x(pc+q)$$

Anybody has a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are right about the first term: $(x+1) - x = 1$ indeed.

**Third term:**
$$
cq^{x+1} - cq^x = cq^x (q-1)
$$
Not sure if $p=1-q$ here and if so, this would be $-pcq^x$.

**Second Term:**

$$
\begin{split}
-\frac{q}{p} \left[1 - q^{x+1}\right] + \frac{q}{p} \left[1 - q^x\right]
 &= \frac{q}{p} \left[q^{x+1} - q^x\right] \\
 &= \frac{q \cdot q^x}{p} (q-1) = q^{x+1}(q-1)/p \\
 &= -q^{x+1} \quad \text{ if } q = 1-p
\end{split}
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: thanks, now I see it!